# read csv file format in hadoop using java code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

How to *read CSV file formats in Hadoop using Java code in eclipse IDE?*

I have very large file in CSV format and i want to access the CSV file in HDFS in order to perform map reduce program. kindly anyone help me in solving the problem.

I want Java code to access the file .

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the file as input to the mapper. The lines of the file will become value to the mapper.

```
class FileMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text> {
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) {
    // process your CSV records here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create you own CSVInputFormat
[CSVInputFormat](https://github.com/mvallebr/CSVInputFormat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CSVTextInputFormat.java)